# CSS and Java within a PHP file

Tags: java, php, html, css

I was wondering how you can organize and be able to use JavaScript, 
CSS, and php on a page. I've been trying to no avail.

It's suppose to be a **blue background** with **white text**. The text will disappear in `90 seconds`.

Code so far:

```html
<?php
    if ($_GET["senator"] || $_GET["microphone"]){
        echo "Please remind". $_GET["senator"]. " to make sure their microphone is" .$_GET["microphone"]. "is on. Thank you.";
 exit();
    }
?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Room 130</title>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready( function() {
   $('#message').delay("90000").fadeOut();
  });
  </script>
  
  <style>
  
   #container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
   }
  
   .message {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
   }
   
   body {
    background-color: #000080;
    color: white;
    font-size: 60px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: JavaScript is not Java

Answer (score 0):

Just put that chunk of php between the  tags... right now it's above the html tag, so it's not being rendered as HTML.